# Embedding folders in a Google File Cabinet and including files in the folders

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sites

Refering to the [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles)  and the section 'Embedding folders in a File Cabinet' I've used this script to control and update a file cabinet in my google sites page.  However, it only works on the root folder and doesn't add files that are in the sub folders.  Please could you help me understand how you pick this up and also control the file cabinet so that it displays this easily?

---

This is the current appscript code:

```
    function showFolderInSite() {
  //var files = DocsList.getFolder("xxxxxxx").getFiles();  commented out this line as using getfolderbyID.
  var files = DocsList.getFolderById('xxxxxxxxxxxxx').getFiles();
  var page = SitesApp.getPageByUrl('https://sites.google.com/x/xxxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxx');
  var attachments = page.getAttachments();

  for (i in attachments) {
    attachments[i].deleteAttachment();
  }

  for (i in files) {
     page.addWebAttachment(files[i].getName(), '', files[i].getUrl());
  }
}
```

I just tried to attach a picture but apparently I need some reputation points to post images.[image: img]. how do I get those?! this is the link to it incase it does work <>  In the meantime the picture shows the folders have been added but there are no files when you expand them.

Edit 5/8/14:  No replies yet (hope someone can help soon).  Some ideas of mine... Do I need to track what is a file and what is a folder and then assume that when the array is populated what comes through after a folder will be what is found in that folder.  One problem with that is how do you differentiate a folder in a sub folder.

Comment: image added with the post :)

Comment: Thanks iDon'tCare, can't see it though - must be something to do with our firewall at this end

Comment: Apologies if I'm sounding a little impatient... is there anyone who could help me / give me some pointers.  I've read up on the .getfolders syntax but my problem is how you then portray that into the cabinet file using the page.addWebAttachment syntax.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
var files = DocsList.getFolderById('xxxxxxxxxxxxx').getFiles();
```

This row returns all the files of the first level in the folder. It does not retrieve any subfolders or their files. This is the same for DriveApp note that Docslist is [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/terms)

So [getfiles()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getFiles()) from DriveApp:

> Gets a collection of all files that are children of the current
>   folder.

This means that you need to recursively fetch all the subfolders and their files. Also note that folders are also files in Google Drive, they only have a different mime type, **application/vnd.google-apps.file**

Your current script fetches the files, including the folders of the current folder, and creates links to those files and folders. It does not upload those files into the file cabinet, only refers to them. If that is the goal, you only need to recurse into the subfolders. Here you also need to note that file cabinets only go one level deep, you will not be able to create a similar structure using the file cabinet if the folders are more than one level deep.

Comment: Hi Jasper.  Sorry for not replying sooner.  Thanks for the reply and your guidance so far.  As long as I were to keep to the one level in google drive, could you tell me how I would go about managing the links in the sub folder?